# Completely terminate activity when onStop happens

Tags: android, android-activity

As per the Activity lifecycle onCreate happens at the first stage, and in my app I execute some vital code in onCreate. Problem is if I hit the home button or put the app in background the activity will not be recreated via onCreate, but through onResume.

I want that once the onStop method is called the app kills itself so that at the next launch it begins from onCreate. If it helps my app is made of only one activity.

(The reason I need this is that copying the necessary code in onResume creates bugs)

Comment: calling `Activity.finish()` should do the trick ... but maybe it would be better to fix "the bugs" in onResume

Comment: I would advise you take a step back and figure out how to accomplish this without subverting the Activity lifecycle. You are asking how to introduce a hack to a fix a bug with your code - rethink your code - otherwise you'll just end up with more (and likely harder to fix) bugs.

Comment: There's probably a more elegantly solution to the problem rather than this hack. Please share more info.

Comment: I am encountering a `BufferQueue has been abandoned` kind of error even if I do modifications that have nothing to do with the camera api itself. It's unelegant but It's the only way of fixing this bug since nobody on the internet has been able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a manifest flag [`android:noHistory`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) for the activity which provides this behavior.

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its `finish()` method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — `"true"` if it should be finished, and `"false"` if not. The default value is `"false"`.
>
> A value of `"true"` means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. In this case, `onActivityResult()` is never called if you start another activity for a result from this activity.

This might be a little bit more secure than using the life-cycle events for it. But keep in mind that any kind of state will be lost afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much it is exactly what I was looking for. Soon I will implement it and report back.